# JavaScript: How to extract multiple values from a sentence using regex?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to extract multiple values from the below sentance

```
var memo = 'BRD-35/21/9: DSI-35/21/641 - 154.0, DSI-35/21/617 - 84.0, TI-23/21223/12 - 78.98';

console.log(memo.match(/DSI\w*/g));
```

I'd like to get result as `['DSI-35/21/641', 'DSI-35/21/617', 'TI-23/21223/12']`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Neither `-` nor `/` are word characters, so trying to match them with `\w*` doesn't make any sense

Comment: try `memo.match(/[A-Za-z]+-[0-9\/]+\s/g)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```js
    var memo = 'BRD-35/21/9: DSI-35/21/641 - 154.0, DSI-35/21/617 - 84.0, TI-23/21223/12 - 78.98';
    console.log([...memo.matchAll(/[,|:]\s([A-Z0-9\/-]*)/g)].map(function(el){return el[1];}));
```

Answer (score -1):

The following regex should do what you want:

```
(DSI|TI)-\d+\/\d+\/\d+
```

Match DSI or TI followed by a `-`, then 3 digits separated by `/`.